# Why does size() provide a wrong size of stack after swapping elements with other stack?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning about C++ STL containers and I am trying to swap the contents of two stacks, and output them afterwards. There is a strange behavior of the second for-loop I use to output the elements of one of the stacks, that I cannot explain to myself - why does the for-loop iterate only 2 times, when myStack2.size() = 3 ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  stack<int> myStack;
  myStack.push(5);
  myStack.push(33);
  myStack.push(6);
  cout << "myStack size: " << myStack.size() << endl;

  stack<int> myStack2;
  myStack2.push(69);
  cout << "myStack2 size: " << myStack2.size() << endl;

  myStack2.swap(myStack);
  cout << "myStack size after swap: " << myStack.size() << endl;
  cout << "myStack2 size after swap: " << myStack2.size() << endl;

  cout << "myStack contents: " << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < myStack.size(); ++i) {
    cout << myStack.top() << endl;
    myStack.pop();
  }

  cout << "myStack2 contents: " << endl;
  for(int j = 0; j < myStack2.size(); ++j) {
    cout << j << ". iteration: ";
    cout << myStack2.top() << endl;
    myStack2.pop();
  }
  cout << "myStack2 size after output iterations: " << myStack2.size() << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
myStack size: 3
myStack2 size: 1
myStack size after swap: 1
myStack2 size after swap: 3
myStack contents: 
69
myStack2 contents: 
0. iteration: 6
1. iteration: 33
myStack2 size after output iterations: 1
```

As you can see there were only two iterations for myStack2 and there is still 1 element in it (5). Can somebody explain this behavior to me?

Comment: Because you're evaluating `myStack2.size()` on every iteration.  Nothing to do with swapping.

Comment: Please post output that match your code. It's a waste of everyone time if the output can not be produced by the program.

Comment: Of course, how did I missed that (headbang) , thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you call pop(), you decrease the size of the stack. And so, first time in the loop you compare j (0) with size(3). Second time, j(1) with size (2). Third time the loop condition is false becase j is 2 and size is 1

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue with your code is that you are re-evaluating the size of respective stack at each iteration (while checking condition of the `for` loop).
At say iteration `i` you pop off an element of the stack and at  iteration `i+1` you again evaluate the size of your stack which is now one less than the original size.
The following changes would help you.

```
int myStack_size = myStack.size(), myStack2_size = myStack.size();

cout << "myStack contents: " << endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < myStack_size; ++i) {
    cout << myStack.top() << endl;
    myStack.pop();
  }

  cout << "myStack2 contents: " << endl;
  for(int j = 0; j < myStack2_size; ++j) {
    cout << j << ". iteration: ";
    cout << myStack2.top() << endl;
    myStack2.pop();
  }
  cout << "myStack2 size after output iterations: " << myStack2.size() << endl;
```